# How to get Block Number

Tags: cleos, transactions, blocks

Which is the **accurate** method to get the `block number` to which a transaction is written after executing a transaction?

The response of `push_transaction` API is not accurate

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use EOSJS

the "result" contains several pieces of information including the transaction id and the corresponding block number.

```
const result = await api.transact({...})
```

Comment: block number in the result could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from the command line using:

`cleos get transaction TRANSACTION_ID | jq '.block_num'`

Comment: I need the block number immediately after the transaction is executed to store it in my database.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail in your question exactly what you want/need?

Comment: I doing server-side transaction signing and push the transaction using push_transaction API. I have to store the returned Block number immediately in my DB for further reference. The problem is, the instantly returned block number is not accurate. I need the correct block number  to which the transaction is written after pushing it